# meta replacing same method in two different tests not working?

Tags: grails, groovy, integration-testing, metaprogramming, grails-2.2

Test controller is as follows

```
def justTest(){

    def res = paymentService.justTest()

    [status: res.status]

}
```

Test service method is as follows

```
def justTest(){



}
```

Now the two test cases are as follows. Payment service method justTest was modified in both cases to return two different values.

```
    @Test
    void test1(){

        PaymentService.metaClass.justTest = {['status': true]}

        def res = controller.justTest()
        assertEquals(res.status, true)


        GroovySystem.metaClassRegistry.removeMetaClass(PaymentService.class)

  }
```

Second test is as follows

```
    @Test
    void test2(){

        PaymentService.metaClass.justTest = {['status': false]}

        def res = controller.justTest()
        assertEquals(res.status, false)


        GroovySystem.metaClassRegistry.removeMetaClass(PaymentService.class)

}
```

One test is failing. When i used debugger, i noticed that this replacement is not working

```
PaymentService.metaClass.justTest = {['status': true]}
```

So i am wondering why one meta replacement is working and another not working? Is it not possible to change the same method in two different test cases using meta programming? I appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: I have not used JUnit but I would suggest to mock `PaymentService` instead of using `metaClass`. Also, try moving the following line as the first line of test `GroovySystem.metaClassRegistry.removeMetaClass(PaymentService.class)`

Answer (score 0):

I would take a different approach:

```
void test1(){
    controller.paymentService = new PaymentService() {
        def justTest() {['status': true]}
    }

    def res = controller.justTest()
    assertEquals(res.status, true)
}
```

Or if you were using Spock instead of JUnit:

```
void test1() {
    controller.parymentService = Stub() {
         justTest() >> [status: true]
    }
    // ...  other code
}
```